# react-native-navigation how to close app notifications

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation's `showInAppNotifications()`, and I would like to be able to use a button from inside the notification I have in order to close it.

Is it possible?

(need support for both IOS and Android.

This is my code:

```
 // show the notification:
 this.props.navigator.showInAppNotification({
    screen: 'Notifications',
    passProps: {
      header: 'Logbook', 
      note:this.props.notes,
      body: 'Recived/Urgent events'
    },
    autoDismissTimerSec: 10, 
    dismissWithSwipe: true
  });


 // the notification itself: 
 class Notifications extends Component {
         render() {
             return (
                 <TouchableOpacitiy
                      onPress={/* Code to close the notification... */}
                  >
                      .  .  .
                 </TouchableOpacitiy>
                  .
                  .
                  .
             );
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.navigator.dismissInAppNotification();`

I do not know why it is not documented.